# Node.js knex - Securing the password used for logging into database

Tags: javascript, node.js, password-protection, knex.js

I have the following code in a file called knexfile.js

```
module.exports = {
    development: {
        client: 'mysql',
        connection: {
            database: 'myDatabase',
            timezone: 'Z',
            user: 'root',
            password: 'myPassword',
            host: '127.0.0.1'
        },
        pool: {
            min: 2,
            max: 10
        },
        migrations: {
            tableName: 'myMigrationTable'
        }
    }
};
```

**myPassword** from the code above is in plaintext. On my production server, I definitely don't want my password in plaintext in my code that my application uses to authenticate with my database. I also wouldn't want it laying around in a file in plaintext on my server.

Is there a way in knex or node to easily handle securely logging into my database? Should I just simply encrypt my password, leave it in a file on my server, and decrypt it using my webapp when it's going to log in?

Comment: You don't decrypt it. You use a one-way hashing function.

Comment: I thought mysql would hash my password again when it receives it and then compare this new hash with what it has stored in its database, which would therefore give an authentication error?

Comment: I don't understand mysql or knex, but what you need to do is hash the user input and compare it to the password in the database. There are algorithms like bcrypt for this, and I recommend salting as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best practice would be using environment variable.

```
knex = require('knex')({
    client: 'mysql',
    connection: process.env.DATABASE_URL
})
```

Comment: So that people know what the connection URL can look like (as a value of the environment variable): mysql://username:password@hostname:port/database

Comment: This just moves the problem elsewhere. Where would the environment variable come from?

Comment: On startup, container will load env var from configmap or secret